# how to not display the entire url under the console when making ajax calls

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have an ajax call under the jquery validate remote method. I am using `Codeigniter`. My code looks like this,

```
$("#formid").validate({
    rules : {
        // username/email
        uname : {
            required : true,
            email : true,
            minlength : 6,
            remote : {
                url : "http://myhost/hmvcfolder/application/modules/modulename/modulesubfoldername/check_email.php", type : "post",
                data : {
                    email : function () {
                        return $('#formid:input[name="uname"]').val();
                    }
                }
            }
        },
    //passwords
        pass : {required : true, minlength : 6}
    },
    //messages
    messages : {
        email : {
            required : "Please enter valid email address",
            minlength : $.format("Enter at least {0} characters"),
            remote : $.format("{0} is already registered!")
        },
        password : {
            required : "Please Provide a password",
            rangelength : $.format("Enter at least {0} characters")
        }
    },
    //on form submitting
    submitHandler : function (form) { // for demo
        form.submit();
    },
    // field messages
    success : function (label) {
        var name = label.attr('for');
        var messages = new Array(
            "Looks good!",
            "You got it!",
            "is Ok!"
        );
        var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
        label.text(name + ' ' + messages[num]).addClass("valid");
        label.select(name + ' ' + messages[num]).addClass("valid");
    }
});
```

This approach goes through and successfully returns a response. When I checked the console using firebug, the post request looks like this

`POST http://myhost/hmvcfolder/application/modules/modulename/modulesubfoldername/check_email.php.`

Is there a way that the `POST` request URL will not look like that without changing the file directory? For instance I would like to make it look like this,

`POST http://myhost/hmvcfolder/check_email.php`

Comment: i am afraid you can't stop that

Comment: The console is recording all HTTP requests being made, so there is no way to amend them, other than by physically moving the file, or using routing to mask the URL.

Comment: Instead make a shorter url or use .htaccess rule to shorten it

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: I think that answers my question. Can you make it answer to this question so that I can accept it? Thank you so much.

Comment: @TsukimotoMitsumasa no problem, I've made it an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The console is recording all HTTP requests being made so there is no way to amend them, other than by physically moving the file, or using routing to mask the URL.